# How do I check if user is already timed out in Discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a timeout command for my own bot since it has more potential than the Built-In one, and I wanted to make a checker if a user is already timed out or not, but as far as I know, there is no variable for that in `guildMember`! Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`communicationDisabledUntil`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=communicationDisabledUntil) or the [`communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp) properties.

The first one returns a `Date` object with the time when the member's timeout will be removed and the second one returns a timestamp.